# Efficient way to convert from string to 0s and 1s, and 0s and 1s to string?

Tags: javascript, performance, binary

I'm writing a bitstream implementation in pure JavaScript. I'm currently representing bits as strings of "0" and "1"s - figured this would be more efficient than arrays of 0 and 1 and I don't want to use Uint32 - and I need to convert strings to and from this representation. Here's what I got so far:

```
function uintToBitString(uint, bit_length) {
    var res = uint.toString(2);
    if (res.length > bit_length) {
        throw new Error("The number " + uint + " is too big to fit in " + 
                        bit_length + " bits");
    }
    if (res.length < bit_length) {
        res = Array(bit_length - res.length + 1).join("0") + res;
    }
    return res;
}

function stringToBinRep(val) {
    var bit_pieces = [];
    for (var i=0; i < val.length; i++) {
        bit_pieces[i] = uintToBitString(val.charCodeAt(i), 8);
    }
    return bit_pieces.join("");
}

function binRepToString(bits) {
    var charCodes = [];
    for (var i=0; i < bits.length; i += 8) {
        charCodes[i / 8] = parseInt(bits.slice(i, i+8), 2);
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, charCodes);
}
```

Although I'm familiar with JavaScript I'm not very well versed in what makes faster code vs. slower code. Is there a more efficient way to do the above using only pure JavaScript?

Comment: Isn't a string implemented as an array of chars?

Comment: @DavinTryon: Probably, yes. What about it though? I have to be able to read/write `n` bits where `n % 8 !== 0`. This is just part of the bitstream protocol I'm writing.

Comment: I was just curious about your comment about it being more efficient to use strings over arrays.  I'm not really a js guy, but I have seen a few articles about string concat performing better than array.join etc.

Comment: is there any particular reason that you're doing `return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, charCodes)` instead of `return String.fromCharCode(charCodes)`?

Comment: @fardjad: Yep, `String.fromCharCode(charCodes)` doesn't work. Try each of the following: `String.fromCharCode(60, 60, 70)`, `String.fromCharCode([60, 60, 70])`, `String.fromCharCode.apply(String, [60, 60, 70])`.

Comment: @fardjad: I do much prefer python's syntax which would look like `String.fromCharCode(*charCodes)`, but alas.

Comment: @Claudiu `String.fromCharCode(65,66,67);` works on **Chrome (v26.0.1410.65)**, also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) says that the parameters are `A sequence of numbers that are Unicode values`. Anyways, I run a quick benchmark and it seems calling `String.fromCharCode` is slightly faster than using apply.

Comment: @fardjad: yes, but `String.fromCharCode([65,66,67])` doesn't work, and I have an array. Thus I have to use `.apply`. Try to get `String.fromCharCode(arrayOfCharCodes)` to work without using apply and let me know if you succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious improvement in `uintToBitString` would be like

```
function uintToBitString(uint, bit_length) {
    var max = 1 << bit_length;
    if(uint >= max)
        throw new Error("The number " + uint + " is too big to fit in " + 
                        bit_length + " bits");
    return (uint | max).toString(2).substring(1);
}
```

As for the two others, I'd rather use `String.replace` there:

```
function stringToBinRep(val) {
    return val.replace(/./g, function($0) { 
        return uintToBitString($0.charCodeAt(0), 8)
    })
}

function binRepToString(bits) {
    return bits.replace(/.{8}/g, function($0) { 
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt($0, 2))
    })
}
```

That said, if performance really matters, you should use ints for bit manipulations and not 1/0 strings.

Comment: nice! wouldn't have thought of that

Comment: Thanks for the `.replace` variants. I will try em out & see how the performance compares. You're right, I should indeed use bit manipulations. I'll see if it's necessary for what I'm doing. So in that case I'd deal with arrays of 32-bit ints? (So I only need 4 bytes for 32 bits, instead of 32 bytes)

Comment: Yes, that will be the case. Note that character != byte if you deal with unicode strings.